# How can I diagnose page jumping in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

With the most recent Chrome update, the screen has started jumping when we click into a text box on a form.  In some cases, it jumps to the top of the page.  If we refresh the page, it stops happening for that page, but if you go to another form, the behavior is back.  We are using Bootstrap 2.x for the forms, but there are also tabs and other layout controls used as well  So, at this point, I am not sure if I am looking at a Chrome bug or an issue in one of the libraries we are using.  How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Do you have any plugins related to the forms? Like `autosize` or `floating labels`, etc. Also, does this only happen with `textarea` or with `inputs` as well?

Comment: No plugins installed other than select2 for dropdowns.  It also happens with textareas and dropdowns, checkboxes and buttons.  When this is going on, you can't select a checkbox or reliably click a button.

Comment: I wonder if visiting [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms) and clicking into a `form` element will also cause the jump? It doesn't on mine (Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m) but curious to see if it persists on your end. Also, have you tried clearing cache and/or testing on other machines?

Comment: Clearing the cache doesn't help.  It happens on every computer with chrome 46.0.2490.71 m on it.  I haven't been able to find any examples of long bootstrap forms anywhere.  Everything is small forms with just a couple of elements.  It doesn't seem to happen there.

Comment: Very odd. And I'm guessing you've already inspected the elements with dev tools to see if on focus there is any css being applied?

Comment: I just created a form with 30 inputs using BS 2.3.2 and wasn't able to duplicate a jumping issue. I'm guessing it's library related. I suppose killing one library at a time and retesting might be a good approach to hunting it down. I'll bump the question to see if it can gain traction!

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the tabs might be involved somehow.  I'm not seeing the behavior on the first tab of a patient record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit seemed to be the ui-layout library that we were using.  At some point today, I noticed that if I resized the window, the jumping didn't happen.  So, I call the ui-layout resizeAll() function when I've loaded the content, and it does whatever it would have done when I resized the window.  All the crazy jumping around is gone.

Thank you camelCase for working with me today to try to troubleshoot this.